# What is considered a continent? - eg for Indonesia's Spice Islanders bonus

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Gajah Mada (Indonesia) gets the Spice Islanders bonus.

> The first 3 cities founded on continents other than where Indonesia
>   started each provide 2 luxury resources (and can never be razed).

What is considered a different continent for these purposes?

My guess would be it has to be separated by ocean, but it could be that just a coastal sea separating landmasses is enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A coastal sea separation is enough - my second city is on an island separated by coastal waters and I've got 2 Nutmeg as a result.

Note that the resource appears on the same spot as the city.

[image]